# How to decrement in python

Tags: python

What's wrong with my code? instead of printing: 10,9,8,7,... it only prints: 9,9,9,9,...

When the edit button is not detected, then loop for maximum of 10 seconds.

Sorry I am new on python. Thanks.

```
def main():

    max_sec = 10
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
            (By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(),'Edit')]")))
        print("detected")
    except:
        max_sec -= 1
        print(max_sec)
        if max_sec == 0:
            sys.exit()
        print("not detected")
        main()

main()
```

Comment: Do not have a function call itself just to go back to the top.  This is called "recursion" and makes the call stack grow for no reason in this case.  Use a `for` loop to count.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are calling `main` in every `except` statement, and the beginning of the `main` function sets `max_sec=10`.

Comment: @helpthenoob -- you may want to try a loop (`for` or `while`) to achieve the results you are after.  Also, I'm sorry somebody downvoted you.  Your question is fine, and welcome to Stack Overflow and Python!

Answer (score 0):

You are recursively calling main from the except block which will reset the max_sec value to 10 every time. Try and move the initial value to the function's arguments.

```py
def main(max_sec):
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
            (By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(),'Edit')]")))
        print("detected")
    except:
        max_sec -= 1
        print(max_sec)
        if max_sec == 0:
            sys.exit()
        print("not detected")
        main(max_sec)

main(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue for you is that you decrement the counter, but the value is not used in the recursive call.

There are many different ways to code this. One possible way is as follows:

```
def main(max_sec=10):  #################
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
            (By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(),'Edit')]")))
        print("detected")
    except:
        max_sec -= 1
        print(max_sec)
        if max_sec == 0:
            sys.exit()
        print("not detected")
        main(max_sec)  #####################

main()
```

Answer (score -1):

just declare the max_sec globally (outsite main would work).